# How can i visit urls with .html suffix

Tags: ruby-on-rails, url, rest

My rails version is **2.3.5**(2.3+)

How can I visit urls with .html suffix?
Just like `localhost:3000/welcome.html` (welcome is a controller).

I got routing errors when I visit urls above.But it works if the url with format param like this:

```
localhost:3000/welcome?format=html
```

In routes.rb:

```
ActionController::Routing::Routes.draw do |map|
  map.root :controller => "welcome"
  map.resources :users
  map.resource :session

  map.connect ':controller/:action/:id'
  map.connect ':controller/:action/:id.:format'
end
```

But but but I found `localhost:3000/users.html` works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this route to connect to an controller:

```
map.connect "welcome.html", :controller => :welcome, :action => :index
```

Whether there is `.html` does not matter for routing purposes, it is just like any other path connecting to any other controller. So no need to modify your controller for this.
Using the `format=html` results in a parameter, so a controller can return the specific type of result, which is not what you want according to your question.

According to your information this (allowing `.html` in your paths) is automatically implemented when creating routes with the `map.resources` method. Since it is working for users in your example.

Comment: That is to say:
if it's not a restful resource(like map.resources :users),I must config named routes for each format request from all kinds of clients(pc,mobile,etc)

html,wml,etc.

now How could it auto display a view page by its suffix(.html, .wml), just restful

Comment: How do you want restful URLs? For users it would be ocme something like `sers.html` for an index action and `users.html/10` and `users.html/10/edit` for a show and edit action? That does not seem right...

Answer (score 1):

You could try this:

```
map.connect ':controller.:format', :action => :index
```